# check_http --ssl still checking HTTP

Tags: https, nagios

Shouldn't the following command return an HTTPS/SSL status code?

```
$ check_http --ssl google.de
HTTP OK: HTTP/1.0 302 Found - 984 bytes in 0,099 second response time |time=0,099305s;;;0,000000 size=984B;;;0
```

It's a simple example, but I can fairly reproduce the malfunction for websites that only respond to HTTPS and have a 302 Redirect. They would be returning the following although they should access on port 443 instead of 80:

```
HTTP OK: HTTP/1.1 302 Moved Temporarily - 585 bytes in 0,079 second response time |time=0,078830s;;;0,000000 size=585B;;;0
```

My version information:

```
$ check_http -V
check_http v1.4.16 (nagios-plugins 1.4.16)

OpenSSL version 1.0.0-25.el6_3.1, latest version from CentOS updates repository
running on CentOS 6 x86_64
```

Comment: I don't understand what this question is really asking. What is an "HTTPS/SSL" status code? The accepted answer will not produce any different result from the examples in the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try running it like this (remove `-vvv` for regular usage):

```
check_http -vvv -S -H <hostname> -u / <IP-Address>
```

Where `hostname` is what is in the `Host:` HTTP Header and `IP-Address` is the IP-Address whereon apache is listening on port 443.

Comment: Having a similar problem with Icinga 1.7.1-7, a Nagios fork. When monitoring the SSL service host that runs HTTPS but not HTTP, Icinga warns about a 403 Forbidden return code. But that warning is for HTTP, not HTTPS.

Manually running the check_http command with either -S or --ssl returns a 200 OK code (and a 403 Forbidden response when run just against HTTP). But the automated service check returns a 403 error with either switch -- check_http!-S or check_http!--ssl.

Icinga does not complain about other SSL hosts, perhaps because they all run HTTP also.

How to fix this erroneous report?